# Table <TR> input values to DB

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have a JS script that adds a `<tr>` and its relevant `<td>` which also adds name depending on how many table data there are.

```
var newRowHtml = '<tr>' +
'<td><input type="text" name="pds_4_input_'+count[0]+'" class="underline_input"></td>' +
'<td><input type="text" name="pds_4_input_'+count[1]+'" class="underline_input"></td>' +
'<td><input type="date" name="pds_4_input_'+count[2]+'" class="underline_input"></td>' +
'</tr>';

table.append(newRowHtml);
```

Resulting in something like this (these ones however are default, so adding one would result in pds_4_input_4 and so on...):

```
<tr>
   <td><input type="text" name="pds_4_input_1" placeholder="Apple"></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="pds_4_input_2" placeholder="Banana"></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="pds_4_input_3" placeholder="Cranberry"></td>
</tr>
```

And I have already built the simple php code to bind those input values into my db and it works.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require 'connection.php';

    function dataToPDS4($mysqli) {
        $input0 = $_SESSION['pds_id'];
        $input1 = $_POST['pds_4_input_1'];
        $input2 = $_POST['pds_4_input_2'];
        $input3 = $_POST['pds_4_input_3'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO pds_4 (accID, Apple, Banana, Cranberry)
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt= $mysqli->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("isss", $input0, $input1, $input2, $input3);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
?>
```

Now, I have to figure out a way to bind the new parameters after pds_4_input_3 brought unto by JS script.

I tried using arrays to bind them in PHP however it seems it doesn't quite work (?) and stupid little me didn't save the code so I can't post it here so; sorry about that.

I'm expecting to just get a link to a video/tutorial or thread that would allow me to save the added table rows and table data. If someone is willing to share part of a code for me to solve as well that'd be swell as well.

That said, thank you in advance and have a good day!

Edit: Forgot to edit `bind_param` types.

Edit 2: Edited the values placeholders in `$sql`.

Comment: Okay, reread the question contents and not really clear what you are asking now. The pseudo code makes it difficult. What about using array notation on the HTML inputs so you dont need to increment them in js? Not really sure that is your issue currently.

Comment: Essentially, I add a new <tr> and <td> to the table when I click on a button. It auto-increments the name depending on the td names (pds_4_input_3) if I add a new <tr> it adds another three (pds_4_input_4, pds_4_input_5, pds_4_input_6).

Now, I need to somehow add that pds_4_input_4 and etc. into the db using php. The thing is, I can't tell how many the user is going to add so I need something to "count" the added table data and then insert it into the db from pds_4_input_1 to pds_4_input_[user input].

Comment: How do you tell `pds_4_input_1` from `pds_4_input_7`? The naming here is pretty confusing, but `<td><input type="text" name="pds_4_input_[]"` couldn't be used, or the `count` value? What is `count` assigned from? Seems like only half the picture is in the question currently.

Comment: I didn't add the entirety of the JS code since it's function is just auto-incrementing a name (pds_4_input_4, pds_4_input_5, pds_4_input_6 and so on..); the problem is in regards to the php code.

Currently, it can handle sending input values from pds_4_input_1 to pds_4_input_3 anything beyond that is just "nope".

So, I want to somehow do the same inserting but with the newly added ones by the user starting from pds_4_input_4.

Comment: You would have to increase the counter value, and check if the next `pds_4_input_X` key (or keys) are still set in $_POST. And keep doing that, until you find a field that doesn't exist any more. Or ... you name your form fields a bit more clever. Adding square brackets to the names will get you an array in $_POST, that you can easily loop over.

Comment: And if your fields have different _meanings_, you can go "multi-level" - `name="pds_4_input[0][apple]"`, `name="pds_4_input[0][banana]"`, `name="pds_4_input[0][cranberry]"` - and with [1] for the next set of fields, and so on. (With this version you'd need to specify the index upfront.)